# What is 3 wire I2C?

Tags: i2c, communication, poe

[image]

This is first time I'm seeing 3 wire I2C and have no idea how it works. How can I implement it in STM32 in Cube IDE using its GUI?

I'm using TI TPS23881 (PSE controller) in one of my projects and I got stuck here in I2C communication.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply tie SDAI and SDAO together. The [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps23881.pdf?ts=1694094560298&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTPS23881) explains that the two pins (which make 3 when combined with SCL) are provided for optoisolated I2C:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. My bad I missed it in datasheet.

Comment: @MuhammadAliJayyad Happy to help. It's a very long datasheet so it's easy to miss.